# Upload File as property of DTO (byte[]) via .Net Single Page Application

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2, single-page-application

I'm developing a web api that as part of its function allows for saving files into a database.

I'll use the dogs as an example. I have a dogDTO:

```
    public class DogDTO
    {
      [Key]
      public int DogId {get;set;}
      [Required]
      public string Name {get;set}
      public string Breed {get;set}
      public byte[] FileAboutDog {get;set}
    }
```

The Controller method takes a DogDTO record (pretend error handling and other useful stuff):

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(DogDTO))]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Dogs")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostDog(DogDTO dog)
    {
      _dogRepository.Save(dog);
      return CreatedAtRoute("Api", new {controller="Dog", id = dog.DogId}, dog);

    }
```

Another developer is creating a test harness as an Asp.Net Single Page Application. The other developer is telling me that he cannot capture the byte array from their test harness and stuff it into the FileAboutDog property of the DogDTO. The developer says that I need to set up the controller to just take form data that will include the byte array and then the API would need to stuff it into the dto and then let the repository do its work.

This seems odd to me. Is there a limitation of capturing a byte array in memory and assigning it to an object before posting? The file sizes we are looking at are not large, and we have no problem enforcing size limits.

If it is reasonably possible to manipulate the byte array in the Single Page Application code, can you provide an example of how this would work?

Comment: Are you able to get the bytes client side via javascript? If so, you could base64 encode the bytes, and then transmit that with your HTTP payload (a string instead of a byte[]). I don't know how you can send a raw byte array as binary data in combination with the rest of your data otherwise if not using forms.

Comment: @crush Thank you; I'm receiving the data, not sending it. The base64 encoding seems like it would work, but I hadn't considered the need to convert everything to JSON (which makes a byte[] not a byte[]), so it would have to be text anyway. I'll update the controller to take form data and the JSON and put them together in the api.

Comment: I assumed you were sending data from a JS based SPA to your WebApi. That's why I suggested before you send your JSON to the WebApi controller, you take the file bytes and base64 them with JS, and make that part of your request to the server instead of raw binary data. Your DTO model would then use a `string` instead of a `byte[]`. You could then convert that base64 back into a `byte[]` server side and stuff it into your domain model. All of this hinges on you being able to base64 the file contents client-side. I know there are base64 javascript libs. Not sure about getting file bytes with JS.

Comment: Sorry, your "other developer ... creating a test harness" would need to make the change to the client-side. You'd make the DTO change. Otherwise, your only option is to use forms I think.

Comment: @crush - We went the Multipart Form Data Route. I'll keep the base64 encoding idea for the future